# Nested dropdown not showing correctly

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my dropdown. When i click the second item in the first dropdown named 'Saturn' a second dropdown will appear. This behaviour is correct only the position of the second dropdown blocks the 'Saturn' label. I would like to have the second dropdown behave the same as when i click 'venus'

```css
.container2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #00002e;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

nav label {
  color: sandybrown;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  float: right;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  top: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

[id^=btn]:checked+ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

nav .menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
  right: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav ul li label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: sandybrown;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li label:hover {
  color: rgb(4, 4, 32);
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
}

nav ul ul li {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  color: sandybrown;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav ul li span {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul li span.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.a {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container2">
    <center>
      <h1 class="ourlabs">Our labs</h1>
    </center>
    <nav class="dropdd">
      <label for="btn" class="button">AndroMedical labs
                    <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <label for="btn-2" class="first">venus
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                   </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.almokhtabar.com/">lab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.medicalcardeg.com/%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AC">lab 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="btn-3" class="second">Saturn
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                   </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.royal-lab.net/">lab 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.alfalaboratory.com/arabic/">lab 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the dropdown moving to the top? Can you please clarify? Here's what I see when I click on the "AndroMedical Labs" https://prnt.sc/148t7vg

Comment: the main container moving to top when I click on the name or the arrow

Comment: You mean that when you click the second link "Saturn" a second dropdown will spawn in front of the label "Saturn" and then you can't click it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question because you have nested dropdowns. I think i found your problem. When the last item in the dropdown is clicked 'Saturn' the appearing dropdown will cover the item in the first dropdown so it does cover the 'Saturn' item. Atleast that's what i think u meant with "Moving to top".I fixed it with adding a margin-top to the ul see the code sample below:

```css
.container2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #00002e;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

nav label {
  color: sandybrown;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  float: right;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  top: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

[id^=btn]:checked+ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

nav .menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: white;
  right: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

nav ul li label {
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: sandybrown;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li label:hover {
  color: rgb(4, 4, 32);
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
}

nav ul ul li {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  color: sandybrown;
  font-size: 17px;
}

nav ul li span {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul li span.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.a {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.last-item
{
  margin-top:58px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container2">
    <center>
      <h1 class="ourlabs">Our labs</h1>
    </center>
    <nav class="dropdd">
      <label for="btn" class="button">AndroMedical labs
                    <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <label for="btn-2" class="first">venus
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                   </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.almokhtabar.com/">lab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.medicalcardeg.com/%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AC">lab 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="btn-3" class="second">Saturn
                   <span class="fas fa-caret-down"></span>
                   </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-3">
          <ul class="last-item">
            <li><a href="http://www.royal-lab.net/">lab 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.alfalaboratory.com/arabic/">lab 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

btw u are also missing a html tag at the beginning

Comment: OK, it was a problem.
but also in the main website when I add this dropdown and click on "Andromedical labs" it moving to up leaving it's area. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: and also there is an arrow button, but I don't know why it is invisible -_-

Comment: The arrow is not visible because the fontawesome library u used for icons is not visible if you don't include the css/javascript

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean by moving up. When i click on your example everything is on a fixed place. Do you mean that the space between the label 'Andromedical' and the dropdown menu is too large?

Comment: I have fixed it.. 
the problem was the (NAV  UL) on the nav bar : 

when I edit it and give Position: absolute; it also change the "dropdown" position.